# How to update the ionic lib of my project from 1.3.1 to 1.3.5? ionic lib update doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I need to update the ionic lib of my project but when I try  '`ionic lib update`' I have the next error

```
    This command has been deprecated.  All resources are currently available in NPM and we recommend that you use NPM to manage these.      
More information is available here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/wiki/Migrating-to-NPM-from-bower

Local Ionic version: 1.3.1  (/Users/esteban.salazar/Projects/Proteccion/ProteccionApp/www/lib/ionic/version.json)
Invalid version: undefined
```

**Ionic info output**

Your system information:

> Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
>   Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1 .
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0 .
>   ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 .
>   ios-sim version: 5.0.8 .
>   OS: macOS Sierra .
>   Node Version: v6.11.2 .
>   Xcode version: Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55

Answer (score 0):

try to update everything like the node.js and the ionic. 
hope my references helps.

=>[Cannot update Ionic-CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977628/cannot-update-ionic-cli/47580711#47580711)

=>[Ionic 2: How to update Ionic library for an existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591456/ionic-2-how-to-update-ionic-library-for-an-existing-project)

Answer (score 0):

I have to manually update with `npm install ionic@version-you-want`