# ERROR: Unable to find command: cap build android

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

Similar to [this question](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-unable-to-find-command-cap-build-android/216360), when I run above commands I got:

```
[ERROR] Unable to find command: cap build android (or ios)
```

I considered all the given answers and points for that question, e.g., I ensured:

1. capacitor is installed
2. android and ios platforms are added
3. uninstalled and installed ionic and ionic/cli and ionic/core.

None of the above solved the problem.
Does any one have any idea how to get it working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was quite easy. As for this [question](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-unable-to-find-command-cap-build-android/216360/8) @jcesarmobile mentioned, the cli was very old version.
You first need to uninstall it via:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
```

Then as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977628/cannot-update-ionic-cli), in macOS, you have to remove the ionic directory (run `ionic info` to see where it is located).

Then reinstall ionic via:

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```